# Removing Comment Character from QStringList

Tags: string, list, parsing, comments, qstringlist

I am parsing the values of a `QStringList` for a commented line where the commented line starts with the "#" character. How would I go about removing the "#" from what I display to the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out how to do what I wanted like so:

```
columnHeaderList << inputLines.remove("#").split("\t");
```